# Gradle multi module project and common tasks

Tags: gradle

I am using a gradle multi project build and I am using allprojects and subprojects to group the tasks, but I have a situation where only a set of sub-projects needs a set of tasks.

ex:: project1 has tasks a,b,c
    project2 has b,c,d
    project3 has d,e,f

I want to try something like

```
projects(':project1',':project2'){
    task b{}
    task c{}
}    
projects(':project2',':project3'){
    task d{}
}
```

But there is no way to accomplish it seems as the projects is not defined in gradle , can someone advice on this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're almost there. Except you need something like

`[':a', ':b'].each { it ->
  project(it) {
    task foo {}
  }
}`